# Min If in excel on Formula applied column with blanks

Tags: excel

I have used Min If function in the past and have got accurate results.But somehow this time i am getting wrong output. I am applying this formula on a column which is the output of certain excel formula. Below is the screen shot for your reference.Column J in the below mentioned screen shot is an output of certain excel formula.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and press **CTRL+Shift+Enter** while entering the formula

```css
=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$105=L4,$J$2:$J$105))
```

In your formula your validating with **B2** cell that is why you haven't got the correct result

Comment: I tried.... I am getting results for Germany-CAM and Germany -OEM... But for Czech I am getting zero even after using the above mentioned formula.

Comment: =MIN(IF($B$4:$B$105=R4,$K$4:$K$105)) this is working fine... instead B2 i have to use B4..,, Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to know you got it :)